# How to scale drawable inside button so that the button size is not controlled by the drawable?

Tags: android

In the screenshot below I'm using the same icon for both the button and the imageview but what I can't seem to control is the scaling of the icon inside the button, I can make the icon smaller by reducing the resolution and make the button smaller but that makes the icon pixelated. Is there any way to have high resolution icons with buttons and let the button control the overall size?

[image]

XML for the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:id="@+id/em_btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email2"/>
```

Comment: Post the code for the Button.

Comment: @Ajay added XML code, I'm not doing anything to the button with Java, I want to do everything with XML if possible.

Comment: Try my answer. I think it will solve your problem. But I highly recommend using mipmap image.

Comment: @Ajay I tried your answer and it looks good, how does mipmap differ?

Comment: When using mipmap the android system will automatically render the image of appropriate resolution based on the device screen. This will avoid rendering a high quality image on a low resolution phone and that avoid unwanted memory usage. - Rendering a high quality image on a low resolution screen have no benefit. --You can take advantage of the Android Asset Studio to create mipmaps https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drawable emailImg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.email2);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.1),
                (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.1));
        ScaleDrawable scaledImg = new ScaleDrawable(emailImg, 0, 10, 10);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.em_btn);
        button.setCompoundDrawables(scaledImg.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

Try this

Comment: This works nicely I just changed the multiplier to 0.2!

Answer (score 0):

On your button, call `setScaleX(floatValue);` and `setScaleY(floatValue);`